# How to open the 'About Device' -> 'Status' page programmatically

Tags: android, android-intent

I have discovered a bug on the `Samsung XCover 2 / GT-S7710.`

When I'm using the `getGsmSignalStrength()` function to retrieve the signal strength, it returns 99 (corresponding to there is something wrong with signal strength reported) until I'm opening the `Settings -> About Device -> Status page`, where it reads out the signal strength and display it. After that, the `getGsmSignalStrength()` function works fine.

My plan is to open the page programmatically when my app starts. I have tried to use this:

```
startActivity( new Intent(Settings.ACTION_DEVICE_INFO_SETTINGS));
```

But that only open the parent page and will not fix the problem. So how do I open the status page, directly when the app is starting?